# Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support .Net Core Project

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am following the tutorial [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-asp-net-core-using-entity-framework-core-code-first/)

for learning the .Net Core. Everything I have installed properly. 
But when I am Running the migration it giving error. [image]

Project.json Code is:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "2.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Please let me know where I am wrong Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't mix up versions. Don't use EF Core tools 2.0.0 with EF Core 1.1
2. Use [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/1.0.0-preview2-final), iirc it is the **LAST** version which supports the project.json structure and hence Visual 2015

It's best to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 and csproj if you want to continue to develop ASP.NET Core applications, since `project.json`-type projects won't be supported/updated anymore. All new versions of the dotnet/PowerShell tools will only support VS2017 with csproj.

### Additionally

Starting with csproj ([Version 1.0.0-preview3-final](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/208)) If you want `dotnet ef` support, you also need to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` for `dotnet ef` commands. Otherwise only powershell commands will be available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)